# Wie sagt man "to parallel park" auf Deutsch

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Ich parke am Strassenrand vor dem Restaurant "Mangiamo".

Ich weiß nicht, ob ich `Längsparken` oder `Am Straßenrand parken` verwenden soll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Längs parken, parallel parken, am Straßenrand parken, das ist alles in Ordnung. Das Gegenstück ist dann eben das Querparken.

Ich bin nicht sicher bezüglich Zusammen- oder Getrenntschreibung. Aber das Verb müsste getrennt und das Nomen zusammen geschrieben werden.

Answer (score 4):

In der Regel parkst Du längs am Straßenrand.

Standardmäßig geht man eigentlich immer davon aus, dass man längs parkt, wenn man am Straßenrand parkt, also brauchst Du es nicht explizit sagen. Es gibt bestimmte Autos, die auch quer am Straßenrand parken können/dürfen, dies ist manchmal sogar gesondert beschildert. Es sind oft Elektro-Autos oder Smarts.

Es wird aber meines Wissens normal nicht gesagt, dass man "längs" parkt, wie im Englischen.

Comment: Ich meine mich daran erinnern zu können, dass Smarts inzwischen nicht mehr auf Längsparkplätzen quer parken dürfen. Nicht dass das für die sprachliche Diskussion relevant wäre ;) Längs wird schon gesagt, hört man ab und zu. Parallel wäre mir eher ungeläufig, habe ich aber auch schon gehört, dann aber eher als "parallel zur Straße". Man darf sich ja auch mal etwas umständlicher ausdrücken :)

Comment: Entschuldige, das mit den Smarts wusste ich nicht - mein Stand war, dass sie dürfen. Zu "längs": ich sagte ja nicht, dass es gar nicht genutzt wird, hier in der Gegend ist es nur eher unüblich bzw. ich glaube, ich habe es zum letzten mal in der Fahrschule gehört. Es ist in jedem Fall wohl die korrekte Bezeichnung.

Answer (score 4):

Was die Schwierigkeit ausmacht, ist nicht die parallele Ausrichtung, sondern der Umstand, daß man dafür gewöhnlich vorwärts und rückwärts manövireren muß, was viele Leute nicht gut beherrschen. Der entsprechende Ausdruck dafür ist also "rückwärts einparken". "Längs einparken" ist zwar theoretisch korrekt, wird aber in der Praxis so gut wie nie benutzt.

Comment: So weit richtig. Die Frage zielt aber nicht auf das Einparken selbst ab, sondern auf den Parkzustand. Die Antwort zur Frage lautet also eigentlich nur "Man parkt am Straßenrand.", was wohl in ~99% der Fälle immer parallel zur Fahrbahn ist.

Comment: Rückwärts einparken kann man übrigens auch quer. Insofern ist "rückwärts einparken" nicht eindeutig.

Comment: Richtig. Einigen wir uns also auf: Es kommt auf die Intention des Sprechakts an: "Wieso bist du so spät?" - "Ich mußte rückwärts einparken." Aber: "Wo steht das Fluchtauto?" - "Ich habe am Straßenrand geparkt." (oder einfach "vor dem Restaurant")

Comment: Heißt das nicht "seitwärts einparken" (der gesamte Vorgang besteht ja ohnehin nicht *nur* in einer Rückwärtsbewegung)? "Rückwärts einparken" bezöge sich dann entsprechend auf eine quer ausgerichtete Parktasche.

Answer (score 0):

Ob du `längs parken` oder `am Straßenrand parken` verwenden solltest, hängt davon ab, was du ausdrücken willst:

`am Straßenrand parken` bezieht sich auf den Ort. Es ist kein besonders angelegter Parkplatz, keine Parkbucht und auch nicht auf der Straße, sondern eben am Straßenrand. In allen Fällen kannst du parallel oder senkrecht parken (wobei senkrecht am Straßenrand nur in sehr seltenen Fällen sinnvoll oder erlaubt sein dürfte).

`parallel parken` bezieht sich auf die Lagebeziehung zwischen Auto und Straße/Parkplatzbegrenzung. Es ist nicht `senkrecht` und auch nicht `schräg`, sondern eben parallel. Wo du so parkst, sagst du damit aber nicht.

Es ist also auch möglich, beides zu kombinieren:

> Ich parke länge am Straßenrand vor dem Restaurant „Mangiamo“.